# Determine which Android app module to run in run-time

Tags: android, android-studio

I have two modules for an app. One for users and one for an admin. How do I decide at run-time which module to run. The question might sound un-clear, let me know in the comments.

EDIT:
What I was trying to do was to install both modules in the app and run one of them at a time. Which was clearly wrong and not possible. Since I can't delete the question, I wrote it here.

Comment: I don't understand the question

Comment: That's not how it works. You gonna do two separate apps. They can be in separate modules (with a third module with code for shared funcionality) or two completely separate projects.

Comment: @Budius, can you write this comment in the answer so I can accept?

Comment: @DivisionSi done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**original comment:**

That's not how it works. You gonna do two separate apps. They can be in separate modules (with a third module with code for shared funcionality) or two completely separate projects

**expanded answer:**

You seem to be a bit confused. A module is just a group of code.

- If you `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` to that module build.gradle than gradle will create an android application (.apk) from it
- if you `apply plugin: 'java'` than gradle will create an java `.jar` file from it
- if you `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` it will create a android library from it (.aar)

For your case you gonna do two separate modules for Android application (`apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`). And a third module with shared functionality (possibly as a library `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`).

The app modules use the library module (`compile project ('lib')`) and generate two separate apks.

Answer (score 0):

You could have Boolean variable, `isAdmin` which could be set to true if the logged in account is an account that holds admin rights. And set up the UI based on the boolean variable.

Answer (score 0):

At runtime in Android Studio?

You pick the runtime target, so `admin:installDebug` compared to `app:installDebug`.

These can be modified within the Run Configurations window, or selected from the Gradle View.

Alternatively, you bundle both UIs together in one app, then hide the views using boolean values. Though, it'd be really easy to bypass that using direct Intents to the activities, for example on rooted devices.